# Open file externally from gvim

Tags: file, ubuntu, vim

In vim on the console, I can move the cursor on the name of a file which lies in the same directory as the currently open file, and issue the command `!xdg-open %:p:h/<cfile>`. This will open the file in an external viewer, as defined by the OS. This is great, but on my system, it doesn't seem to work when using gvim.

This is the command I put into my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <leader>o :silent !xdg-open %:p:h/<cfile><CR>
```

What do I have to do so that this works both in vim on the console *and* in gvim?

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 12.04LTS.

Comment: What happens, do you see any errors? It should work the same way in gvim.

Comment: no, I don't see any errors. The status line displays the exact same command to be executed as in vim, I hear the harddrive rattle a bit, and nothing happens.

Comment: here I tried with `gedit`, your problem cannot be reproduced.. :(

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/386646/xdg-open-url-doesnt-open-the-website-in-my-default-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an `&` at the end of the command.  I learned this from how [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/blob/cc784a55d26af74fea41bd1f162a40a2c43b5de7/ftplugin/latex-box/common.vim#L178) does it.

Answer (score 1):

Following this post here: https://superuser.com/a/407675/104415, putting a `&` at the end of the command makes it work in both gvim and vim:

```
nnoremap <leader>o :silent !xdg-open %:p:h/<cfile>&<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
:set debug=msg
```

and then see whether there are any errors?